# Stored Procedure para concatenar un varchar y un numero entero incremental en campos con datos repetidos - SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2014

Necesito editar el nombre de un campo (en caso de que ya exista) de mi tabla en mi base de datos en SQLServer 2014.
•   Si el parámetro @pNombreTarea es NULL o vacío, se crea un Nombre automático siendo este YYMMDD de la fecha de creación y en caso de existir una Tarea con ese nombre, se le concatenará “_” y un número incrmental en 1 iniciado en 1, y se buscará la primera no ocurrencia, por ejemplo 110920, luego 110920_1 y luego 110920_2. En caso de que el parámetro @pNombreTarea se especifique, se buscará que no exista una Tarea con ese nombre dentro del @pResourceID. En caso de existir, retorna -4. Caso contrario continúa.
Lo que tengo hasta el momento es esto pero no funciona:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_VerificarNombreTarea] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pNombreTarea varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @var int = 0
declare @pUniqueID int
declare @pType int
declare @pStartDate smalldatetime
declare @pEndDate smalldatetime
declare @pAllDay bit
declare @pLocation nvarchar(max)
declare @pStatus int
declare @pLabel int
declare @pResourceID int
declare @pResourceIDs nvarchar(max)
declare @pReminderInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pRecurrenceInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pTimeZoneId nvarchar(max)
declare @pCustomField1 nvarchar(max)
declare @Cant int

set @Cant = (select count(*) from Appointments where subject = @pNombreTarea)
    if @Cant > 0
    begin
        set @pNombreTarea = @pNombreTarea + '_' + CAST(@Cant as varchar(max))
    end 
    else
        return @pNombreTarea  
END
```

La tabla donde almaceno los datos es la siguiente:

```
UniqueID PK, int
Type int,
NombreTarea nvarchar(max),
StartDate datetime,
EndDate datetime,
AllDay bit,
Location nvarchar(50),
Description nvarchar(max),
Status int,
Label int,
ResourceID int,
ResourcesIDs nvarchar(max),
ReminderInfo nvarchar(max)
```

### Aclaración:

El SP lo llamo desde la capa de datos de mi aplicación y el nombre de la tarea lo obtengo de un formulario para crear tareas en un calendario.

Comment: Y de donde sale el valor de @pResourceID para verificar si la tarea ya existe o no?

Comment: También sale del formulario para crear las tareas, ya están cargados por defecto.

Comment: @PabloMatias no hiciste esta pregunta ya? la reporte como duplicada, cual es la diferencia con la pregunta anterior?

Comment: Considero que esta pregunta está mejor redactada que la anterior, si queres elimino la anterior y dejo esta

Comment: La anterior tiene una respuesta, alguien se tomo el trabajo de responderla. Y siempre puedes editar la pregunta para que quede mejor redactada. Si en realidad no era lo que querias preguntar, puede dar como aceptada la respuesta a esa pregunta y preguntar sobre otras cosas en una pregunta nueva. Siempre se recomienda cerrar una pregunta aceptando la respuesta que haya solucionado el problema, o pedir aclaraciones hasta solucionar el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, espero que sea lo que necesitas :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_VerificarNombreTarea] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pNombreTarea varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @var int = 0
declare @pUniqueID int
declare @pType int
declare @pStartDate smalldatetime
declare @pEndDate smalldatetime
declare @pAllDay bit
declare @pLocation nvarchar(max)
declare @pStatus int
declare @pLabel int
declare @pResourceID int
declare @pResourceIDs nvarchar(max)
declare @pReminderInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pRecurrenceInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pTimeZoneId nvarchar(max)
declare @pCustomField1 nvarchar(max)
declare @Cant int

    -- Primero verificamos si el valor viene vacio
    if @pNombreTarea='' or @pNombreTarea is NULL
    begin
        set @pNombreTarea = Format(GetDate(), 'yyMMdd')

        set @Cant = (select count(*) from Appointments where subject like @pNombreTarea+'%')
        if @Cant > 0
        begin
            set @pNombreTarea = @pNombreTarea + '_' + CAST(@Cant as varchar(max))
        end 
        return @pNombreTarea  
    end
    else
    begin
        -- Si el string de @pNombreTarea ya esta dentro del string @pResourceID
        if CHARINDEX( @pNombreTarea, @pResourceID ) > 0
            return -4
        else
            return @pNombreTarea
    end 
END
```